# Проверка поля input[text]

Tags: javascript, html

Как проверить поле input[text] ? Только вот не отправляя форму. Есть кнопка "Дальше" нажимая на эту кнопку проверяется поле. если заполнено то проходим дальше. извиняюсь может как то сумбурно все описал

Comment: А в чём проблема? Напишите проверку, там легко.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самом просто варианте, у нас есть поле и есть обработчик

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form') // ссылка на нашу форму
const nextButton = form.querySelector('.next-step') // ссылка на кнопку
const input = form.querySelector('input[name="text"]') // ссылка на наш инпут

// навешиваем обработчик
nextButton.onclick = function () {
    alert(input.value); // значение хранится в св-ве value
}
```

```css
button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form id='form'>
   <input type='text' name='text'><br>
   <button class='next-step'>Далее</button>
</form>
```

То есть что бы получить значение поля, вам нужно иметь ссылку на него + обратиться к св-ву `value`